# Identify pandas column that contains None value

Tags: python, pandas, nonetype, geopandas

I have a geopandas dataframe `gdf` that looks like the following:

```
   Id  text  float                           geometry
0   0  1.65   0.00  POINT (1173731.7407 5354616.9386)
1   0  None   2.20   POINT (1114084.319 5337803.2708)
2   0  2.25   6.55  POINT (1118876.2311 5307167.5724)
3   0     0   0.00  POINT (1179707.5312 5313710.8389)
```

How can I identify the column/s that contain a `None` value?

I have tried using the following list comprehension without success:

```
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gp

gdf = gp.read_file('/temp/myshapefile.shp')

s = [pd.isnull(col) for col in gdf.columns if True]
```

Which results in:

```
In [1]: s
Out[1]: [False, False, False, False]
```

My desired output in this case is:

```
['text']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
print(gdf.isna().any())
```

will give output which column contains null in terms of `true` or `false`

```
Id       False
text     True
float    False
geometry False
```

---

So use this

```
print(gdf.columns[gdf.isna().any()].tolist())
```

output:

```
['text']
```